# How to search for multiple values in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I am new to coding... I have to create a dictionary from a database (which I believe I was able to do so) but I haven't found any example on how to search for multiple values. In this case I want the code to bring me the  name of the person that all numbers match (AGATC & AATG & TATC) not just one.
So for instance if input is 2 8 3 (my variables count1 count2 count3) the result should be Alice.

Any help/direction will be appreciated.

This is how my dictionary looks like:

```
{'Alice': OrderedDict([('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')]), 
 'Bob': OrderedDict([('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])
 ...
```

And this is my code so far:

```
from sys import argv
import csv
import re

#Opens the database and the sequence specified in the command-line argument
if len(argv) == 3:
    database = csv.DictReader(open(argv[1], 'r')) #opens the file in dictionary format
    s = open(argv[2])
    sequence = s.read()
else:
    print("Missing command-line argument")

#Counts how many times STR repeats in the sequence by changing the STR definition to the maximum it found

str1 = "AGATC"
count1 = 0
while str1 in sequence:
    count1 += 1
    str1 += "AGATC"
print(count1)

str2 = "AATG"
count2 = 0
while str2 in sequence:
    count2 += 1
    str2 += "AATG"
print(count2)

str3 = "TATC"
count3 = 0
while str3 in sequence:
    count3 += 1
    str3 += "TATC"
print(count3)

#creates an empty dictionary
data_list = {}

#fill the dictionary
for row in database:
    key = row.pop('name')
    data_list[key] = row
print(data_list)
```

Comment: Dictionary are made for key → value lookups. Searching for values is not efficient but possible by iterating through all items and applying a condition manually. If your code does many lookups you should consider adapting your data structure to your search.

Comment: So the name of the person, i.e. Alice and Bob, are your _keys_ in the dictionary, not your values. Your values are `('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')` etc. for that key. As Klaus has mentioned, dictionaries are really only for looking up information, not necessarily for indexing. This is because dictionary data types are unordered. However, you may make this into a list instead.

Comment: To help give you the best end-to-end solution, could you post an example of the CSV data you have?

Comment: I'd advise to create a dictionary like `{(2, 8, 3): 'Alice', (4, 1, 5): 'Bob'}`. If number tuple are not unique: `{(2, 8, 3): ['Alice'], (4, 1, 5): ['Bob', 'Charles']}`

Comment: Thanks everyone, Abhishek answer did the trick, but just for learning purposes what data structure you guys would recommend? Something like a hash table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely agree with previous comments on using a better data structure, I believe the following might help you for now :

```
from collections import OrderedDict 

x = {'Alice': OrderedDict([('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')]), 
 'Bob': OrderedDict([('AGATC', '4'), ('AATG', '1'), ('TATC', '5')])}

lst = [2, 8, 3]

for k in x.keys():
    if lst == [int(y) for y in x[k].values()]:
        print(k)
```

Comment: had to add typecasting to int to make it comparable to the lst of ints

Comment: Thanks so much, the solution was to put my search values into a list, simple but brilliant (for me at least) :)

Comment: you should answer with your own solution, get those rep points!

Answer (score 0):

So this was my solution:

```
from sys import argv
import csv
import re

if len(argv) == 3:
    database = csv.DictReader(open(argv[1], 'r')) 
    s = open(argv[2])
    sequence = s.read()
else:
    print("Missing command-line argument")

str1 = "AGATC"
count1 = 0
while str1 in sequence:
    count1 += 1
    str1 += "AGATC"

str2 = "AATG"
count2 = 0
while str2 in sequence:
    count2 += 1
    str2 += "AATG"

str3 = "TATC"
count3 = 0
while str3 in sequence:
    count3 += 1
    str3 += "TATC"

lst = [count1, count2, count3]

data_list = {}

for row in database:
    key = row.pop('name')
    data_list[key] = row
# print(data_list)

indicator = 0
for i in data_list.keys(): 
    if lst == [int(y) for y in data_list[i].values()]: 
        print(i)
        indicator += 1

if indicator == 0:
    print("No match")
```